# QTableView items was draw differently in PyQt 5.8 and 5.9

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

It happened when I use the following code on win7 32bit,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # ui = QMainWindow()

    path = r'D:\BaiduYunDownload\untitled'
    model = QFileSystemModel()
    model.setRootPath(path)

    table = QTableView()
    table.setModel(model)
    table.setRootIndex(model.index(path))

    # ui.setCentralWidget(table)
    table.resize(800, 600)
    table.show()

    viewOptions = table.viewOptions()
    print(table.wordWrap(),
          int(viewOptions.textElideMode),
          int(viewOptions.decorationAlignment),
          int(viewOptions.displayAlignment),
          int(viewOptions.features))

    app.exec_()
```

there is only one file with the long name(for test): 
`A directory model that displays the contents of a default directory is usually constructed with a parent object.txt`
 in dir `D:\BaiduYunDownload\untitled`

In PyQt 5.8 (installed via `pip3 install pyqt5==5.8`)
[image]

In PyQt 5.9.1 (installed via `pip3 install pyqt5==5.9`)
[image]

I wonder why the QTableView item in the `Name` column was draw differently ? I checked with the following  property in the code, all returned the same value in both version of PyQt .

```
print(table.wordWrap(),
int(viewOptions.textElideMode),
int(viewOptions.decorationAlignment),
int(viewOptions.displayAlignment),
int(viewOptions.features))
```

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a Qt bug. Check out Qt's bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22572).

One workaround consists in setting font properties via CSS.